# Slider doesn't start - CSS only

Tags: css, slider, css-animations

I create a slider with some logos, but the animation doesn't start. I create it with only css but it remains blocked. I check few time the code but I can find the answer.
The slider should scroll and change the logo, but it doesn't work.

I think that it could be also created with javascript but I'm not sure how to do it.

Can someone help me?

```css
.slider {
  width: 960px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.slider::before,
.slider::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, width 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  z-index: 2;
}

.slider::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.slider::after {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}

.slider .slide img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.slider .slider-track {
  display: flex;
  width: calc(200px * 20);
  animation: scroll 4s ease 3s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(calc(-200px * 10));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider-track">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="./1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="./2.png">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="./3.png">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="./4.png">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="./5.png">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="./6.png">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="./7.png">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="./8.png">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="./9.png">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="./10.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The culprit is your `animation` syntax. For the correct syntax, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation. You can defining two animations, but you you are define one animation with two times and two timing functions. For instance removing the `3s` and the `ease` would fix the syntax problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your animation property is wrong.

use these properties instead. This is more readable and it makes it easier to avoid similar mistakes:

```
animation-name
animation-duration
animation-timing-function
animation-delay
animation-iteration-count
animation-direction
animation-fill-mode
animation-play-state
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation.asp

```css
.slider {
  width: 960px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.slider::before,
.slider::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, width 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  z-index: 2;
}

.slider::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.slider::after {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}

.slider .slide img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.slider .slider-track {
  display: flex;
  width: calc(200px * 20);
  animation: scrolll 4s ease;
}

@keyframes scrolll {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(calc(-200px * 10));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider-track">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="./1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="./2.png">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="./3.png">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="./4.png">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="./5.png">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="./6.png">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="./7.png">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="./8.png">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="./9.png">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="./10.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```